# Mongodb - unique Ids with count()

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I build a site with referral links to products and working with mongodb. 
We all know that the long _id field looks ugly in Urls e.g. http://website.com/p/532600d9a715ea980a00002b/u/532af835a715eae43f00002c.

I have read some posts here and googled a while and wondered why people don't generate this easy unique id:

1. Count current documents in collection
2. add 1 to the number
3. append a field to document called e.g. 'unique'

So each document got a unique number starting with 1 and urls would look like this then http://website.com/p/1/u/2.

I won't delete any document.

Where is the problem with this solution?

Comment: The Problem? You need to count all documents, what can take some time. In the meantime, another one could do the same -> id conflict. Furthermore you are doing an operation that is not necessary. If you still would like to do it this way, think about querying the collection statistics instead of counting all documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sane variant of this approach, where you increment a **counter** and assign that number, is [part of the official documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/).

The problem with your approach is that counting is a relatively **expensive** operation. Moreover, it's **not even collision safe** because two threads could count simultaneously and get the same number, so the second insert will fail.

Generally speaking, sequences create a bottleneck because you need a single point of coordination. For a write-heavy system, the number of operations is *doubled* (an additional `$inc` for every insert). To make matters worse, sequences leak a lot of information to the outside (i.e. the number of entries in the database).

If you're running a web shop, blog, etc. you probably want your URLs to be a lot prettier, descriptive and SEO-friendly like `/products/displays/27-inch/iiyama-2734FW`.

If you're building a web application where the URLs aren't visible to search engines anyway, I believe that neither `/users/433` nor `/users/532af835a715eae43f00002c` will be a reason for your customer to choose or not choose your application. Maybe a wise customer would, but then they'd reject the former option...